# Trigger jquery function on input when clicking other input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a dinamically added input form. I want to make it so when an input loses the focus, its value get `.00` appended to it. So far I tried this:

```
$(".money-input").on("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on("click", function (e) {
  $(".money-input").each(function() {
    var valTemp = $(this).val();
    if ((valTemp.indexOf(".00") < 0) && (valTemp != "")) {
      valTemp += ".00";
      $(this).val(valTemp);
    }
  });
});
```

My problem is, it only works when I click on other divs but inputs. Additionally what I also want to achieve is when I edited something on one input then switch focus to other input, the previous input value got appended by `.00`.

Any help appreciated! :)

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well?

Comment: Related: [jQuery lose focus event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423561/jquery-lose-focus-event)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$(".money-input").live('blur', function() {
    var valTemp = $(this).val();
    if ((valTemp.indexOf(".00") < 0) && (valTemp != "")) {
        valTemp += ".00";
        $(this).val(valTemp);
    }
});
```

[`blur`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) is your 'lost-focus' event. With using [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) it will attach this event to elements that exists now and in the future (since you are dynamically adding a form).

Answer (score 1):

The requested behavior is odd...use the **[`step` attribute](https://www.wufoo.com/html5/minmaxstep-attributes/)** instead:

```
<input type='number' step='01'>
```

The minimum requirements to have a floating point value in an input is to have: `type="number"` and `step` attributes. In the following Demo there are 3 forms with 2 inputs each for a total of 6 inputs.

1. The first 2 inputs have no `step` attribute.
2. The second pair are dynamically created. The first input has no `step` attribute whilst the second one does.
3. The last pair of inputs have the `step` attribute.

---

- I modified the styles so when an input has the `step` attribute, its borders are red dashed lines. It's not necessary to do this, it's just for demonstration purposes.
- There is a jQuery on event handler registered on 2 events, one is **[`blur` event](https://api.jquery.com/blur/)** and the other is the **[`change` event](https://api.jquery.com/change/)**. These events trigger the same handler which will set the `step` attribute to an input upon the triggering of either `change` or `blur` events.

---

### Demo

---

```js
$('#form1').append("<input id='i2' class='money' type='number' value='0.00'>").append("<input id='i3' class='money' type='number' value='0.00' step='.01'>");

$('.money').on('blur change', function(e) {
  if ($(this).val() > 0) {
    $(this).attr('step', '.01');
  }
});
```

```css
input[step*=".01"] {
  border: 1px dashed red
}
```

```html
<form id='form0'>
  <input id='i0' class='money' type='number' value='0.00'>
  <input id='i1' class='money' type='number' value='0.00'>
</form>

<form id='form1'></form>


<form id='form2'>
  <input id='i4' class='money' type='number' value='0.00' step='.01'>
  <input id='i5' class='money' type='number' value='0.00' step='.01'>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```